# What can cause RDS (Reliable Datagram Sockets) to be enabled?

Tags: vulnerability

In May 2019, [CVE-2019-11815](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2019/CVE-2019-11815.html) was reported, which is a vulnerability in the RDS (Reliable Datagram Sockets) kernel module.

Yesterday (23rd July 2019), a kernel patch for the vulnerability was released under [USN-4068](https://usn.ubuntu.com/4068-1/).

RDS is blacklisted by default in Ubuntu, under the `rare-network` modprobe blacklist config file.

However, what can cause RDS to be enabled? Could installing a package from the Apt repositories cause this? Is there a list of packages that can cause it to be enabled? Or would the blacklist always have to be manually removed?

I can see that RDS is definitely not loaded using `lsmod`, however I would like to determine whether it could have been loaded in the past, or if there is potential for it to be loaded in the future because of a package or system configuration.